# Custom Connection ID in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS's Websockets and having a hard time dealing with fetching the ConnectionID. I understand that every user should have a unique connection ID but is there a way to manually set the ID?
Im having trouble with this because every time the user disconnects and reconnects, a new ID is used as connection ID. I am storing the ID in a central database but its getting messy to do this.
So I was wondering is there is a way to set 1 ConnectionID to each of my users

Current Lambda Function Code

```
import json
import pymysql
import boto3


connection = pymysql.connect(
  host="MyHost",
  user="MyUser",
  password="MyPassword",
  db="MyDB"
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  number = event['queryStringParameters']['number']
  connectionID = event['requestContext']['connectionId']
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("UPDATE My_TABLE SET CONNECTION_ID = %s WHERE NUMBER = %s", [connectionID, number])
  connection.commit()
  

  return {
    "statusCode": 200,
  }
```

Although this works fine, there are some situations where its not feasible. So I need to permanently assign an ID to a user or find a way to custom generate.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Store the connection id in the users browsers (cookie or local storage) and send it along. Even if the user disconnects and reconnects you would re-send the "old" id. Obviously, you need to figure out invalidation of that ID depending on your context.

Comment: Its for a Mobile Application @Jens

Comment: Mobile applications can have storage too. On disk, in memory or a database. It is probably even easier with them. On iOS you could use a simple file in the apps container or CoreData or Keychain or just store it in the apps memory.